# Buggy vectors in quiver plot (Gradient of of Voltage) with matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I edited some examples to make a simulation for the voltage superposition of 2 point charges and made a 3D surface plot, the code is the following:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib import cm

    q1 = 2e-9
    q2 = -2e-9
    K = 9e9

    #Charge1 position
    x1 = 2.0
    y1 = 4.0
    #Charge2 position
    x2 = 6.0 
    y2 = 4.0

    x = np.linspace(0,8,50)
    y = np.linspace(0,8,50)
    x, y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

    r1 = np.sqrt((x - x1)**2 + (y - y1)**2)
    r2 = np.sqrt((x - x2)**2 + (y - y2)**2)

    V = K*(q1/r1 + q2/r2)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, V, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.rainbow,
        linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
    fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
    plt.show()
```

[3D Surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThnUH.png)

Now what I want to do is a contour plot with a vector (quiver) plot on top of it. I tried the following code, but I get a bunch of buggy vectors coming out of both charges, even the negative one:

```
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(1,1)
cp = ax2.contourf(x, y, V, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
fig2.colorbar(cp)

v,u = np.gradient(-V, 0.2, 0.2) #E = -∇V

ax2.quiver(x, y, u, v)  
ax2.set_title("Point Charges")
plt.show()
```

[Buggy vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOxOY.png)

I suspect that the long vectors are related to a division by zero. The vectors should come out of the positive charge and get into the negative one. But how would I go about fixing them? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO, very nice MWE. One option would be to exclude all vectors beyond a certain length by setting them to NaN. Here I use the 95th percentile.

```
r = np.sqrt(u**2 + v**2)
is_valid = r < np.percentile(r, 95)
u[~is_valid] = np.nan
v[~is_valid] = np.nan
x[~is_valid] = np.nan
y[~is_valid] = np.nan

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(1,1)
cp = ax2.contourf(x, y, V, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
fig2.colorbar(cp)

ax2.quiver(x, y, u, v)
ax2.set_title("Point Charges")
ax2.set_xlim(0, 8)
ax2.set_ylim(0, 8)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, that was very helpful. Also thanks for the welcome.